# Errors when starting Rails Server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

im quite new to ruby and rails. I have just installed Ruby, DevKit, Rails and a few gems.
I just created my first rails project and everything seemed good until i tried to start the server(rails server) The error message is below. I cannot grab the whole error because there is alot of errors and the command lines starts to remove it.

Update 1, Full Log
[Error Log](http://pastebin.com/BicJBUaU)

Comment: We need to see the top of the error. You are only showing us the error starting at line 412. Please update the question with the full error log.

Comment: Okay, managed to get the full error log.

Comment: Have you tried uninstall then reinstall mysql gem?

Comment: No that did not work unfortunately.

Comment: did you run: rake db:create, rake db:migrate?

Comment: Just tried that, it gave the same error or a very similar error as the one i posted.

Answer (score 1):

Cause: "The libmysql.lib included in the MySQL Connector/C 64 bit is not compatible with the mingw64-gcc compiler."

[This page](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8591) details how to fix the problem.